# non nested model comparison using R

Tags: r, model-comparison

To explain my problem , i have this simulated data using R.

```
require(splines)
x=rnorm(20 ,0,1)
y=rep(c(0,1),times=10)
```

First i fitted a regular (linear effects) logistic regression model.

```
fit1=glm(y~x ,family = "binomial")
```

Then to check the non linear effects, i fitted this natural spline model .

```
  fit2=glm(y~ns(x,df=2) ,family = "binomial")
```

Based on my thinking models , i believe these 2 models are non nested models.

Next i wanted check whether the non linear model (`fit2`) has any significant effects compared to the regular logistic model (`fit1`).

Is there any way to compare this two models? I believe i cannot use the `lrtest` function in `lmtest` package, because these two models are not nested models.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Methods and theory questions belong on CrossValidated.com

Comment: This seems like the case of a simple `anova(fit1, fit2, type = 'Rao')`. This will give you a p-value whether the two models explanatory power are significantly different. Based on the result, you could then continue to check your model assumptions, (`cumplots`, etc. for distributional assumptions) and choose the model which performs the best while not breaking the model assumptions.